# CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638 in python opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have made a face detection program but it's giving me three errors and I tried to solve them through various sites but couldn't find a clear solution

```
import cv2  
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml') 
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')  
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
while 1:  

    ret, img = cap.read()  
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5) 

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces: 
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),2)  
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w] 
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w] 

        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)  

        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes: 
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,127,255),2) 

    cv2.imshow('img',img) 

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27: 
        break
    
 cap.release()  
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The above code is giving me an error like this

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-m9hy83n6\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (912) CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\code material\Rough.py", line 9, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-m9hy83n6\opencv \modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-m9hy83n6\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

please can someone help me with this

Comment: please check that ret returning True. If not then video is not capturing.

Comment: and also check that your web cam is enable.

Comment: @sourabmaity I checked, my webcam is enabled but ret is returning False

Comment: if your camera is used by other instance of your code, that scenario this error can come. example one working opencv code is capturing camera. that time you can run same code in other instance, for second instance this error will come.